# Boundedness of a bilinear mapping

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $X$ be Banach spaces and let $B: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a bilinear mapping,

Assume that $\forall x \in X$ there exists $M_{x} \geq 0$ such that $|B(x,y)| \leq M_{x}\|y\| \space \space \space \space \forall y \in Y$

and that

$\forall y \in Y$ there exists $N_{Y} \geq 0$ such that $|B(x,y)| \leq N_{y}\|x\| \space \space \space \space \forall x \in X$

Now I have to use the boundedness principle to prove that there exists $K \geq 0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq K \|x\| \|y\|$

could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the family of maps $B_x:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ defined by $B_x(y)=B(x,y)$. $|B_x(y)|=|B(x,y)|\leq M_y\|x\|$.
This implies that for every $y\in Y$, $Sup_{\|x\|=1}|B_x(y)|\leq M_y\leq +\infty$.
The uniform boundedness principle implies the existence of $K>0$ such that
for every $y\in Y, x\in X, \|x\|=1, |B_x(y)|=|B(x,y)|\leq K\|y\|$.

This implies that for every $x\in X, y\in Y$, $|B({x\over{\|x\|}},y)|\leq K\|y\|$. We deduce that $|B(x,y)\leq K\|x\|\|y\|$.

Comment: Note this proof only requires that Y is a Banach space (used when applying the principle of uniform boundedness).